# commands cheatsheet software

Tags: gratis, open-source, command-line

I usually save my commands guide in .txt files with notes about these commands, as we cannot remember all commands is really useful for me to have this kind of .txt files for some processes/commands that I use time to time.

Do you have any recommendation for creation of your own cheatsheet? I use notepad++ because I don't really write a long description for every command, I like reading man pages and keeping things in my head, however, I'm pretty sure notepad++ is not the best option and there must be really good software for this. Do you know any opensource/free software for this?

Thanks a lot.